# Get users except logged user

Tags: reactjs, filter

I don't know how to form my question, but I'll try explain my problem. So I'm creating local meet app similar as (tinder). But I spent about 2 hours and can't figure out how to create a logic, that when I get all users from database I display all users at main page, but there is a problem, it also display the user which is already logged in and he can see himself at main page. Is there any solution to display all users except that user which is logged in? I was trying to use filter method, but can't figure it out how to create correct logic or maybe there's a simple method how to do it?

There I'm getting all users and display them:

```js
export default function HomePage() {
    const [allUsers, getAllUsers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUsers() {
            const resp = await get('api')
            getAllUsers(resp)
            console.log(resp)
        }
        fetchUsers()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className='home__page'>
            <Toolbar />
            <div className="home__users">
                {allUsers && allUsers.map((users, i) => <SingleUser users={users} key={i} />)}
            </div>
            <footer className='footer'>
                <p>All rights reserved by Cartoon Match organization. To read more about our policy <Link to='/policy'>click here</Link>. </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

There's SingleUser component:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function SingleUser({ users }) {

    return (
        <div className='single__user'>
            <img src={users.image[0]} alt="" />
            <h3>{users.firstName} {users.lastName}</h3>
            <h4>{users.gender}</h4>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm also have a users `secret` saved in `localstorage`, maybe it could be easier to think simple solution

Comment: Have you tried using `Array.filter(...)` before calling `getAllUsers(resp)`?

Comment: Umm.. Nope do you have any example of that? Cause I tried only when I've get `getAllUsers`.

Comment: How to do you store logged user information and what is structure of single user? Is that some object?

Comment: @Andyally I'm posting users in `MongoDB` database, with `_id_`, `secret`, `username` and etc. And have a get all users route from where I'm taking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'll have access to the current loged in user stored in a global context, after user login. And there're two ways to filter the item you don't want to render in a list:

#### 1. Conditional rendering (using `&&` the Logical AND operator) inside the `map()` method:

```
export default function HomePage() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] == useState(); // <- stores current loged in user
    const [allUsers, getAllUsers] = useState([])

    return (
            <div className="home__users">
                {allUsers && allUsers.map((user, i) => user.id !== currentUser.id && (<SingleUser users={user} key={user.id} />))}
            </div>
    )
}
```

#### 2. Filter the list first and then render it, by chainning array method `list.filter().map()`:

```
export default function HomePage() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] == useState(); // <- stores current loged in user
    const [allUsers, getAllUsers] = useState([])

    return (
            <div className="home__users">
                {allUsers && allUsers.filter(user => user.id !== currentUser.id).map((user, i) => <SingleUser users={user} key={user.id} />)}
            </div>
    )
}
```

Array method accept an callback function, that we can spcify some condition, and check if every iteration of the item in the array meet such condition, if it meets the condition, then return the item, and `filter()` as a whole returns a shallow copy of the array itself, so we can continue to chain the method with `map()`:

```
allUsers.filter(user => user.id !== currentUser.id).map(user => {...})
```

This means, if the user with `id` not equal to the loged in user, then return the `user` item.

See more at MDN docs: [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND), [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Dmn.. I had similar code, but first I've used map and than filter.. Thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: Glad it helped, it's generally recomended to __mark an answer as accpeted__ when it solves you problem, it will help future reader with similar problem, and indicate that, the issue is solved with a solution. You can do this by checking `✔` in the top left corner of the answer.